# randomForest: Credit card fraud advice

Tags: r, classification, random-forest

data source: https://www.kaggle.com/mlg-ulb/creditcardfraud

I have a dataset with approximately 280,000 rows and 31 columns. This dataset has records of credit card transactions and has flagged the fraudulent ones. 99.8% of the data are legitimate transactions, and 0.2% of the data are fraudulent. Since the data is so imbalanced, I used weighted randomForest to classify NotFraud cases vs. Fraud cases.

Currently, I think my model fits the data very well to the point of overfitting. However, I am not sure if it is overfitting because the data is naturally imbalanced at  99.8% real transactions. This is what my outcome looks like:

```
#training
> actual <- as.factor(c(0,0,1,1))

> predicted <- as.factor(c(0,1,0,1))

> count <- c(191204,40,98,228)

> df1 <- data.frame(actual,predicted,count)

#testing
> actual <- as.factor(c(0,0,1,1))

> predicted <- as.factor(c(0,1,0,1))

> count <- c(56852,9,26,75)

> df2 <- data.frame(actual,predicted,count)
```

Question 1: What can I do to make the model more general and reduce overfitting? Do I delete variables from the model? If so, how do I identify and remove these 'weak' indicators?

Question 2: How can I improve this model overall? I want to increase the amount of true positives and reduce the amount of false positives & false negatives.

I have tried setting ntree to 100, 200, and 500. From what I understand, it did not seem to make much of a difference in my results.

```
> set.seed(123)

> data_set_size <- floor(nrow(df)*0.80)

> index <- sample(1:nrow(df), size = data_set_size)

> training <- df[index,]

> testing <- df[-index,]

> rf <- randomForest(Class ~ ., data = training, ntree = 4, importance = TRUE, classwt = c(0.3,0.7))

> results <- data.frame(testing$Class, predict(rf, testing[,1:30], type = "class"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Question 1, `how do I identify and remove these 'weak' indicators?`, you should focus upon feature selection: supervised or unsupervised. Where supervised feature selection methods consist of methods like correlation, missing value treatment while unsupervised feature extraction methods are principal component analysis, factor analysis. The idea here is to reduce data dimensionality such that features accounting for maximum variance are retained, while features with low variance are discarded.

For `Question 2: How can I improve this model overall?` Focus on either `5-fold` or `10-fold` cross-validation schemes. To determine the optimum number of trees to improve accuracy, see these similar questions, [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36165/does-the-optimal-number-of-trees-in-a-random-forest-depend-on-the-number-of-pred), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189344/choosing-random-forests-parameters), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348245/do-we-have-to-tune-the-number-of-trees-in-a-random-forest), [4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7295/what-should-be-the-optimal-parameters-for-random-forest-classifier) and [5](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/53240/practical-questions-on-tuning-random-forests)

A minimal working example for Question 2 is given below:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.ensemble import  RandomForestClassifier
import pandas as pd

diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()
X, y = diabetes.data, diabetes.target

clf=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators =10, random_state = 42, class_weight="balanced")
output = cross_validate(clf, X, y, cv=2, scoring = 'accuracy', return_estimator =True)
for idx,estimator in enumerate(output['estimator']):
    print("Features sorted by their score for estimator {}:".format(idx))
    feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(estimator.feature_importances_,
                                       index = diabetes.feature_names,
                                        columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance', ascending=False)
    print(feature_importances)
```

**Output**

```
Features sorted by their score for estimator 0:
     importance
s6     0.137735
age    0.130152
s5     0.114561
s2     0.113683
s3     0.112952
bmi    0.111057
bp     0.108682
s1     0.090763
s4     0.056805
sex    0.023609
Features sorted by their score for estimator 1:
     importance
age    0.129671
bmi    0.125706
s2     0.125304
s1     0.113903
bp     0.111979
s6     0.110505
s5     0.106099
s3     0.098392
s4     0.054542
sex    0.023900
```